# Web scraping error selenium: name 'records' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium

I get this result:

```
line 72, in <module>
    writer.writerows(records)
NameError: name 'records' is not defined
```

This is my code :

```
def main(search_term):
    records = []
    url= get_url(search_term)
    
    for page in range(1,21):
        driver.get(url.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div',{'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
        
        for item in results:
            record = extract_record(item)
            if record: 
                records.append(record)
            
    driver.close()        


#save data to csv file 
with open ('results.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Title','Current Price', 'Original Price', 'Rating', 'Reviewscount','Reviews', 'Url'])
    writer.writerows(records)
    
main('Bluetooth earphones')
```

Comment: `records` is a local variable defined in `main()` and therefore cannot be accessed outside of this function. You can either make `records` a global variable or have `main()` return it so as tu use it during saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `main()` function return the `records` list, and use the returned value in the `writer.writerows()` method:

```
def main(search_term):
    records = []
    url = get_url(search_term)
    
    for page in range(1,21):
        driver.get(url.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
        
        for item in results:
            record = extract_record(item)
            if record: 
                records.append(record)
            
    driver.close()   
    return records # return list
  
records = main('Bluetooth earphones') # Get returned list

#save data to csv file 
with open ('results.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Title','Current Price', 'Original Price', 'Rating', 'Reviewscount','Reviews', 'Url'])
    writer.writerows(records) # Use returned list
```

Answer (score 0):

`records = []` is defined within *`main(search_term)`* method:

```
def main(search_term):
    records = []
```

To access `records = []` outside the `main()`:

```
writer.writerows(records)
```

you need to define/declare in the global scope as follows:

```
records = []
    def main(search_term):
        url= get_url(search_term)
        .
        .
        for item in results:
            record = extract_record(item)
            if record: 
                records.append(record)
        
#save data to csv file 
with open ('results.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Title','Current Price', 'Original Price', 'Rating', 'Reviewscount','Reviews', 'Url'])
        writer.writerows(records)
```